# IEnumerable<T> processing instead of List<T>, can deferred execution cause issue

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

In the code, I process `IEnumerable<T>`, persisted to the in memory cache, where first time it goes to database and fetch the result as `IEnumerable<T>`. Data processing includes the following operations:

1. Filter data on various columns
2. Multi column sort the filtered data and take a subset (1 page = 100 records)
3. Calculate numerical columns summary like Sum, Avg, Min, Max for the filtered data

Overall the data processing is a fairly complex logic, which includes using Reflection and expression trees to filter based on user input and operators.

Till now, I use to convert the `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>` using `ToList()` first time, for ease of processing and there on will Typecast the `IEnumerable<T>` to `List<T>`, as result of all the Linq and other operations is `IEnumerable<T>`. Now as the data in the system has started increasing, even that is hurting the performance, since doing the `ToList()` on 2 -3 million records takes up 2-3 sec, which we want to avoid, as we are trying to finish the call 1-2 sec, including rendering the data to user, who finally gets just 100 records. It would prudent to do the memory allocation on that final 100 records.

Important questions related to `IEnumerable<T>` processing that I have are:

1. It is deferred execution, which means various Linq operations on it will process, only when we want to work with the result. Is it also the case for fetching data from database. My understanding is no, since that is a blocking operation and will fetch the memory stream, so deferred execution will only be the issue with Linq to objects, and in that case too we need to be careful about closure issues.
2. An operation like `Count()`, or `foreach`, do they cause `IEnumerable` to allocate the memory similar to `ToList()` or they instead process the pending deferred operations and then just work with an enumerator to process the result
3. Is it a better strategy to completely shift the overall processing to `IEnumerable<T>`, which surely limits the APIs access, but another challenge I find following two operations mentioned in the beginning Sort-Paginate and Summary Calculation are done in parallel using Task API on filtered data, would this make each of them separately execute the data filtering, which is approximately filtering 2 million records to 100 K and thus cause more performance issues

**Edit 1: (Clarification)**

I use Dapper.Net to fetch the data from database, which internally wraps a List inside the IEnumerable, which can thus be used for further processing

Comment: If you have the results of a database query as an `IEnumerable` then you've already done something wrong. You will already have the complete set of items in memory at the point you have an enumerable, so there is no reason for this not to already be a List or an Array. All you're doing by taking an IEnumerable and calling ToList on it, is copying it from one array that already exists into a new array. You should look at your query to see how it can be optimized to return a List immediately and avoid this re-allocation

Comment: @caesay *You will already have the complete set of items in memory at the point you have an enumerable* **???** What?? Why?? It depends on the technology he uses to return the result set... Clearly there are some limitations, but if you keep the connection open, you can easily translate a `SqlDataReader` to a `IEnumerable<>` and have only one line at a time in memory.

Comment: @Mrinal *An operation like Count(), or foreach, do they cause IEnumerable to  allocate the memory similar to ToList()* Your comprehension of `IEnumerable<>` is probably quite low... Enumerating (even `Count()`ing) an `IEnumerable<>` not backed by a List/array/collection in memory causes it to be "regenerated"... So if you Count() + enumerate it for showing it, you could cause TWO queries to be executed. NEVER enumerate twice a `IEnumerable<>` IN ANY WAY (even `Count()`,`Any()`,`FirstOrDefault()`) unless you are ready to pay a double execution or you are sure that the data is already in memory.

Comment: @xanatos thanks for the details, my understanding of IEnumerable<T> is not as poor, but surely I didn't explain the details well. I am using Dapper micro ORM to fetch data, whose Query<T> provides IEnumerable<T>, which internally contains List<T>, so yes I already have the memory allocated. Now does this means all the operations on IEnumerable<T> will be supported by the data structure allocated internally, List<T> in this case. Would it be a prudent approach to Type cast the IEnumerable<T> here on and use the allocated memory effectively for data processing, instead of using IEnumerable

Comment: @caesay since I use Dapper internally, so it already allocates List<T>, so your point was correct, I can just use the same memory by simple type casting

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Note that Dapper can work in "Buffered" mode (the default one I think) where it produces a `List<T>` or in non-buffered mode where it works in streamin mode and returns a non-backed `IEnumerable<>`

Comment: @xanatos I checked that, I am using default Buffered mode, thanks

Comment: If the operation is being remoted to a database then why are you using `IEnumerable`? You should be using `IQueryable`.

Comment: @EricLippert My options for IQueryable with Sql Server like Entity Framework, Linq2Sql, doesn't provide desired performance. We fetch as IEnumerable, store in the memory cache and run custom filtering, sorting and computing logic, which works well in terms of performance

Comment: @EricLippert in fact my understanding is we need to change under lying database (Sql Server) to a system that has good IQueryable options, so that we can do all the processing at the source, currently document dbs, like Raven seem to be alternative, but will take sometime to shift